# Return random record from a has many through association in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a controller method that currently returns a random record.

Controller

```
 @recipe =  Recipe.order('RANDOM()').first
```

The model that it queries has a has_many through association to another table.

I would like to return a random result based on the association.

Models

Recipe

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :name

  has_many :recipe_seasons
  has_many :seasons, through: :recipe_seasons
end
```

Season

```
class Season < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :recipe_seasons
    has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_seasons
end
```

Recipe Season

```
class RecipeSeason < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :season
end
```

I have so far

```
@date = Time.now
@month = @date.month
@season = Season.find(@month)

@recipe =  Recipe.where(recipe_seasons: @month).order('RANDOM()').first
```

This returns me the one recipe with the recipe_season id of the value stored in the month varible. What I actually want is one recipe from the season_id with the value stored in the variable @month.

Taking a complete guess, I tried:

```
@recipe =  Recipe.where(recipe_seasons: season_id: @month).order('RANDOM()').first
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
@season = Season.find(@month)

@recipe =  Recipe.where(season: @season).order('RANDOM()').first
```